# UILabel dynamic width with sizeToFit on a cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, sizetofit

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UILabel` inside on the `Storyboard`. I set the text of this `UILabel` dynamically and I need to resize the width of the `UILabel` accordingly because after it I have another `UILabel` that must stay side to side.

I am trying with

```
> MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
> author = @"Some dynamic text";
> cell.authorLabel.text = author;
> [cell.authorLabel sizeToFit];
```

What happens: 
at the first render the `UILabel` just keeps the width that is set on the `storyboard`, thus either the text is cropped or there is too much space after it.

After scrolling, the cells are dequeued and the `sizeToFit` method is applied properly, but is too late because the second `UILabel` is already positioned on the wrong place.
(cannot post picture due to low reputation restriction)

Any idea?

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947970/dynamic-calculation-of-uilabel-width-in-uitableviewcell?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

maybe you mean something like that:

```
MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
author = @"Some dynamic text";
cell.authorLabel.text = author; <-- excluded in your code
[cell.authorLabel sizeToFit];
```

If this doesn't work, try to use some like this:

subclass UITableViewCell and rewrite the method below:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL) selected
{ 
    [super setSelected:selected];
    [self.authorLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

Comment: Sorry to forget the line that you correctly added. Anyway this still doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

use this one for getting dynamic height and width,

```
CGSize sizeDynamic  = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX,CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

you can get,

```
sizeDynamic.height and sizeDynamic.width values
```

Comment: This works to properly resize the `UILabel` based on the content, but I still have the problem that in this way the side-by-side label is not moved so it doesn't respect the horizontal spacing constraint and the final result is two text overlapping. Should I calculate the new position of the second label based on the new width of the first label?

N.B. If this `sizeWithFont` works and `sizeToFit` on the same point doesn't work, what am I missing about `sizeToFit` method?